# C++ fgets failed to read all output from popen

Tags: c++, linux, popen, fgets

In my code, I use popen with cmd 'iostat -xk 2 2'. Generally the iostat cmd will output a report to stdout and sleep for interval 2 seconds, then output another report to stdout.

When I use fgets to read from popen pipe, weird things are: I only get the first report. fgets hangs there and I never get the second report 2 seconds later. I change the function fgets to fgetc but it didn't help.

Here is my C++ code:

```
string iostatCMD = string("iostat -xk 2 2 ");
FILE *iostatFile = popen(iostatCMD.c_str(), "r");

int fd = fileno(iostatFile);
string readall;
while(!feof(iostatFile))
{
    char buffer[128];
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, iostatFile) != NULL)
    {
        cout <<buffer;
        readall += buffer;
    }
}
cout <<"readall = " <<readall <<endl;
```

I give it a try with Python. It works very well with popen, I get two reports by iostat and no hangs:

```
subprocess.Popen('iostat -xk 2 2', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0];
```

So my question is how to read continuely all the output from popen pipe in C++?

Comment: Your loop should be `while (fgets(buffer, 128, iostatFile) != NULL)`.  Testing `feof` there does nothing useful.

Comment: BTW, I tried your original program and the program with my suggested modification, and both work fine on my Linux box.  Not sure what's happening for you.

Comment: Yes, thanks. There is a confliction with other parts of components. Sample code would work on normal Linux platform.

Comment: I don't see what other parts or components would interfere with this.  The code is rather straightforward.